# When previewing my site–its perfect, but when uploading online–my slider doesn't work.

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, image-uploading

I am a bit new with Java and HTML/CSS and I was wondering if anyone can help me out with this. I have built my entire portfolio site and when I preview it in Safari and Firefox it looks great. However, when I put it online it shows that the images are still loading and the slider isn't working due to the "loading" icon.

I would appreciate it so much if someone can help me with this. I have been up all night looking at the FAQ for the slider I got and can't find out what my deal is... I also tried to use the original versions of the jquery files to see I edited something wrong, but still found no answer.

Thanks so much!

My site is www.shelbylynnebaker.com and it's uploaded and not working if you wish to look at the HTML/CSS coding in-depth

Comment: Seems like you are missing the images from the images/ folder

Comment: ...or the path is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The images is not found:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.shelbylynnebaker.com/images/1.jpg"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.shelbylynnebaker.com/images/2.jpg"
```

etcetera

You probably forgot to upload them?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me narrow this down. Apparently, although I was selecting the image files and uploading them (both the image folder and then attempting to do the files each individually) - it wasn't going through. I ended up having to synchronize with the remote server. Which, to be honest, I am still unclear what happened that I had to do that, but thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting some images not loading which could have something to do with it: 'blank.png' and '1.png' aren't loading.

Also it looks like there is an issue with the Google Fonts you're trying to use.

Open your site in Firefox with Firebug installed and look at the Net tab.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me narrow this down! Do you know what the problem could be with the google font? 

I was informed by a friend who is a hundred times better at web design than me, that I could just insert the code and it would work... So is it something that I did? I am going to look through and try and find out, but if you have any pointers I would appreciate it!